# Quantum Fourier Transform for general cyclic groups

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-fourier-transform

The QFT on the group $\mathbb{Z}_N$ is given by
\begin{equation}
QFT\,|k\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} e^{2\pi i\,jk/N}|j\rangle\,.
\end{equation}

The usual circuit implements the QFT with $N=2^n$ on $n$ qubits. Does anyone know how to realize this transformation when $N$ is not a power of 2? I have found an algorithm that approximates a QFT with arbitrary $N$, but I would like to find out if some exact circuit is known. I think that it should at least in some cases, since the problem 5.1 of Nielsen and Chuang's book is to find it when $N=p$ is a prime number.

I'm interested in particular on the $\mathbb{Z}_3$ transform, which corresponds to the matrix
\begin{equation}
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,\begin{pmatrix}
         1&1&1 \\ 1&e^{2\pi i/3}&e^{-2\pi i/3} \\ 1&e^{-2\pi i/3}&e^{2\pi i/3}
    \end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{equation}

Of course it acts on a 3d space, so to realize it using qubits we should extend it to a unitary operator on at least a $2^2$ dimensional Hilbert space. One possibility could be

\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt3 }
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1&1&1 \\ 1&e^{2\pi i/3}&e^{-2\pi i/3} \\ 1&e^{-2\pi i/3}&e^{2\pi i/3}
        \end{pmatrix} &  \\
                     & 1
    \end{pmatrix}\,,
\end{equation}
but then how can we realize it exactly? When $N=2^n$ we can get the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}$ prefactor with the n Hadamard gates that prepare the uniform superpositions, but now that $\sqrt{3}$ factor is really bothering me.

Answer (score 4):

Kitaev [gave](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9511026) an algorithm to approximate Quantum Fourier Transform over an arbitrary cyclic group.

Later, Mosca and Zalka [showed](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301093) how his construction can be made exact.

You can find a nice description for Kitaev algorithm in [Dave Bacon](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse599d/06wi/) lecture notes for example.